# Error asignando valores a una clase

Tags: c#, objeto

[image: Debug en VS]Estoy implementando una cola para almacenar comandos de ejecucion en forma no sincronizada, y se me ocurrio construir la siguiente solucion, pero no esta funcionando, para nada, es mas hace cosas muy extrañas ... y no tengo ni idea de porque. Haciendo un debug, cuando recupero los registros de la clase, los elementos tienen todos el mismo contenido, EL ULTIMO EN INGRESAR (al finalizar, es mas el primero esta vacio). Y cuando asigna el segundo elemento a "command" modifica el primero, es dificil de explicar lo que pasa (al final del post lo explico mejor). Si hay dudas pregunten ...

```
    OrderQueueDet = new ordersQueueDetail();
    OrderQueue    = new ordersQueue(16);

    (...)

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando1";
        OrderQueueDet.nameOrder     = "1";
        OrderQueueDet.posiciones    = 1;
        OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber   = 1;

        OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);
        OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando2";
        OrderQueueDet.nameOrder     = "2";
        OrderQueueDet.posiciones    = 2;
        OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber   = 2;
        OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);

        OrderQueueDet.command = "Comando3";
        OrderQueueDet.nameOrder = "3";
        OrderQueueDet.posiciones = 3;
        OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber = 3;
        OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);
     }
```

Estas son las clases:

```
    public class ordersQueueDetail
{
    public string command;
    public int tradeNumber;
    public int posiciones;
    public string nameOrder;
    public string tendencia;

    public ordersQueueDetail()
    {
        this.command = "";
        this.tradeNumber = 0;
        this.posiciones = 0;
        this.nameOrder = "";
        this.tendencia = "";
    }
    public void assing_ordersQueueDetail(string pcommand, int ptradeNumber, int pposiciones, string pnameOrder, string ptendencia)
    {
        this.command = pcommand;
        this.tradeNumber = ptradeNumber;
        this.posiciones = pposiciones;
        this.nameOrder = pnameOrder;
        this.tendencia = ptendencia;
    }
}

public class ordersQueue
{
    public int idxQueue;
    private int maxQueue;
    public ordersQueueDetail[] ordersQueue_;
    public ordersQueue(int nQueues)
    {
        this.idxQueue = -1;
        this.maxQueue = nQueues;
        this.ordersQueue_ = new ordersQueueDetail[nQueues + 1];
    }
    public bool add_Queue(ordersQueueDetail pOrdersQueueDetail)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (this.idxQueue < this.maxQueue)
        {
            this.idxQueue++;
            this.ordersQueue_[this.idxQueue] = pOrdersQueueDetail;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Pasa que cuando ejecuto este bloque de codigo

```
    OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando1";
    OrderQueueDet.nameOrder     = "1";
    OrderQueueDet.posiciones    = 1;
    OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber   = 1;
    OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);

    OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando2";
```

En esta instancia OrderQueue.ordersQueue_[0].command es igual a "Comando2".
Alguien sabe porque? Ya que todavia no ejecuta la asignacion al elemento 2 .. parece como que queda enganchado un puntero de memoria, alguien sabe donde esta el ERROR?????

Gracias!!!

Comment: Saludos. Prueba ya sea agregando un clone/copia de la clase; o si  es un bucle crear la variable a agregar en el mismo bloque (según corresponda) con alcance donde se agrega.

Comment: Excelente, gracias!!!! Estoy feliz!!! ja

Answer (score 0):

Claro, es porque hacen referencia al mismo objeto y se queda el último valor.
Te recomiendo que cada vez que vayas a insertar, crees un nuevo OrderQueueDet , de tal manera que sea un nuevo objeto.
Espero poder ayudar.

Comment: Si señor!!!!!  Funciono!!! Mil gracias capo!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

En tu código siempre estas haciendo referencia al mismo objeto, cada ves que quieras agregar un nuevo comando debes crear un nuevo objeto `OrderQueueDet`, el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
OrderQueue    = new ordersQueue(16);

(...)

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creamos el primer comando 
    OrderQueueDet = new ordersQueueDetail();
    OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando1";
    OrderQueueDet.nameOrder     = "1";
    OrderQueueDet.posiciones    = 1;
    OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber   = 1;
    OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);

    //Creamos el segundo comando 
    OrderQueueDet = new ordersQueueDetail();
    OrderQueueDet.command       = "Comando2";
    OrderQueueDet.nameOrder     = "2";
    OrderQueueDet.posiciones    = 2;
    OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber   = 2;
    OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);

    //Creamos el tercer comando y así cada ves que haya que agregar uno nuevo
    OrderQueueDet = new ordersQueueDetail(); 
    OrderQueueDet.command = "Comando3";
    OrderQueueDet.nameOrder = "3";
    OrderQueueDet.posiciones = 3;
    OrderQueueDet.tradeNumber = 3;
    OrderQueue.add_Queue(OrderQueueDet);
 }
```